# AndroidX Crypto library, unable to save file after encryption

Tags: android, encryption, androidx, fileoutputstream

I'm using [androidx.security.crypto](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/package-summary) library to encrypt a text file. I'm [following the docs here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedFile).

```
val keyGenParameterSpec = MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC
        val masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(keyGenParameterSpec)
        val secretFile = File("/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/testfile.txt", "super_secret")
        val encryptedFile = EncryptedFile.Builder(
                secretFile,
                applicationContext,
                masterKeyAlias,
                EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB)
                .setKeysetAlias("file_key1") //this is optional
                .setKeysetPrefName("secret_shared_prefs1") //this is optional
                .build()
    }
```

After encryption, how do I save it to a file ?

Comment: `/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/testfile.txt` this does not exaclty qualify as following the doc. Does that folder exist ? Do you have permission to write in that folder?

Comment: This is a remake of your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58859357/androidx-crypto-library-is-unable-to-encrypt-txt-files?noredirect=1#comment104009624_58859357). The document is already provides you how to save the file. You need write permission, too.   See the [developer.android.com/topic/security/data](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data#java)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Android Cryptography](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography), you build an encrypted file as shown in your code example and then get a `FileOutputStream` by using the `openFileOutput()` method. This you can use like a normal FileOutputStream, with an OutputStreamWriter or something similar. From the [website](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography), in Java:

```java
// Write to a file.
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    encryptedFile.openFileOutput()));
writer.write("MY SUPER-SECRET INFORMATION");
```

Or in Kotlin:

```java
// Write to a file.
encryptedFile.openFileOutput().bufferedWriter().use {
    it.write("MY SUPER-SECRET INFORMATION")
}
```